# Root Android phone

Tags: android

I have created a database for my app and I want to check .db folders to check the data inserted while developing. But my Android mobile will not allow to access data folder. To achieve this I have rooted my mobile with GingerBreak.apk. Device rebooted but nothing happened. How can I check my data base from my phone.

Note: I can't check the data using emulator, because app cant run on emulator, it uses, Bluetooth, WiFi,etc.

Regards,

Krishna

Comment: First of all, are you sure you have your phone rooted? What is your phone model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install some file broswer(such as R.E file manager) to access to these .db files. They are located in /data/data/{package name} dir.

Meanwhile, you can access these file via command line.

For emulator:

1. Type `adb shell` in the command line, and you can see a `"#"` prompt.
2. Type 'cd /data/data/{package name}` to go to the very dir where the
   .db file is located.
3. Now type `sqlite3 <db file name, no extension>` so that you can execute SQL command to read and control the .db file. Now you can see a `"sqlite>"` prompt.

For real device(phone must be rooted):

Step 2 and 3 are the same. In Step 1, you have to type "adb shell", and then "su" to see the "#" prompt.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To root your phone. You can use [lucky patcher app](http://www.lucky-patcher.co/).Although there are plenty of apps available around internet but i found it worth using
By using this app you can not only root your device as well as remove annoying ads and much more.